# Novel about a girl with butterfly poison on her face, who used to be a poison tester?

Tags: story-identification, novel

Do you know the novel where the female protagonist was reborn in a girl who has butterfly poison on her face (I think) that saves a prince that was plotted by his fiancée to get to his brother to be empress? The original owner of the body was slowly poisoned.

She was a poison tester who was granted the right to marry and then her son gave her a fruit (which is the reason for her being reborn).

The guy pretends to have amnesia when he returned because he was victim of a plot by his fiancée.

The girl also eats all kinds of poisons and then it produces tattoos on her body which she can summon.

Comment: Hi Unknown Me! I took the liberty of re-writing your title to make it more descriptive (avoid titles like "can't remember the title", because contributors can't decide whether to click on them). If you think you can do better, please feel free to re-edit your title :)

Comment: This has some similarities with Maria Snyder's Poison Study series. In the first book the protagonist Yelena  becomes a poison tester and she is poisoned by a slow acting poison called *Butterfly Dust*. But I don't think tattoos are involved.

Comment: @Unknown Me   Did you write that someone was trying "to get his brother to be empress"?  As a general rule, brothers are male and empresses are female, though of course sometimes magic users can change genders.

Answer (score 3):

"[The Shameless Young Miss](https://www.wattpad.com/story/108351269-the-shameless-young-miss)" by "passtheduch" should be the book you are looking for. You can find it on Wattpad.

Summary of first few chapters:

> The story goes that the protagonist dies of old age, and wakes in the  body of a young miss that had been maltreated and left in the wild. To save herself she moves to a cave where she finds the prince and helps him escape his imprisonment. Her new body has been poisoned and since she had learned the art of poison before she can make them into tattoos, hence the butterfly tattoo on her face.
>
> They return and it turns out that the prince had been imprisoned because his childhood sweetheart had too much ambition or couldn't resist her family's ambition, and she(fiance) had married his brother the emperor.